# Attempting to read a txt file - locking up

Tags: c#, split, streamreader, readline

I am trying to read a certain part of textfile. The text looks like the following:

```
[HRZones]
195
175
156

0

[SwapTimes]

[Trip]
474
0
6616
-223


[HRData]
84  182 87  -222    129 4139
84  182 87  -222    129 4139
88  179 86  -222    133 3640
95  185 92  -222    136 3393
103 193 91  -222    123 4666
107 196 94  -222    125 5684
107 198 96  -222    128 4919
109 197 95  -222    131 4926
110 198 96  -222    134 4655
111 196 95  -222    126 4154
```

The file actually contains a lot more lines under the [HRData] section.

I am trying to grab the [HRData} using the following code. Sadly, this locks up the program; a breakpoint shows this happens in the first while loop.. almost like it can't see anything?

```
 private void readFile()
    {
        //read the hrm file and split values
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file_name))
            {
                string line;

                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != "[HRData]")
                {
                    line = sr.ReadLine(); // FAILS HERE.. 
                }

                while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string split = line;
                    string[] values = split.Split('\t');
                    foreach (String value in values)
                    {
                        hrdata[i, j] = int.Parse(value);
                        i++;
                        if (i > 5)
                        {
                            i = 0;
                            j++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The file_name is being passed from a previous check and the data seems good.

Comment: You're reading two lines at once before comparing one of them to `[HRData]`... you need to get rid of the `line = sr.ReadLine();` inside the loop so you are only reading one line at a time.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

Here you check one line and skip *the next* one. Avoid second `ReadLine`.

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != "[HRData]")
{
    line = sr.ReadLine(); // FAILS HERE.. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for EOF and Trim() it to make text equality to work. Following should work

```
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = sr.ReadLine();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line) && line.Trim() == "[HRData]")
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string split = sr.ReadLine();
                string[] values = split.Split('\t');

                foreach (String value in values)
                {
                    hrdata[i, j] = int.Parse(value);
                    i++;
                    if (i > 5)
                    {
                        i = 0;
                        j++;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

As some have already pointed out, you're reading a line during the loop condition and then again in the body of the loop so this could work or fail depending on whether `[HRData]` appears on an odd or an even line of the file.

Re-write the `while` loop as a `for` one instead:

```
for (var line = sr.ReadLine();
     line != null && line != "[HRData]");
     line = sr.ReadLine()) { /* NOP */ }
```

And if you can afford to use LINQ, then the following is even simpler and doesn't require any brain gymnastics:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines().SkipWhile(s => s != "[HRData]")) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With that loop you risk to jump past the line that contains your searched text because you read a line two time but test only one time

```
 string line = sr.ReadLine();
 while (line != null && line != "[HRData]")
 {
     line = sr.ReadLine();
 }
```

If the file happens to have one more line before the loop probably it would have worked but the bug is still there

Comment: Thank you very much - will accept as soon as it lets me :)

Answer (score 0):

2 things I noticed:

1) You have **no** check for the `[HRData]` "tag". You check for the line not being the tag and not null.

2) I think you while loops as a whole do not know to stop reading at the end of the file.